# Почему некоторые разработчкики записывают числа в 16-ричном представлении? (C#)

Tags: c#, системы-счисления

Здравствуйте!
Достаточно часто в open-source проектах замечаю, что разработчики записывают числа не так:

```
int i = 2147483647;
```

А так:

```
int i = 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

Даёт это один и тот же результат: у нас имеется переменная, содержащая значение = int.MaxValue, но в чем глубокая логика такой записи? Просто, мол: "Я умею записывать числа в 16-ричном представлении, посмотрите на меня!"
Или же тут есть некоторые плюсы? Может, присвоение идет на наносекунды быстрее и/или машине их проще так воспринимать? Разрешите, пожалуйста, мои сомнения по сему поводу!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Очевидно, что данное значение инициализатора

```
int i = 2147483647;
```

запомнить сложно. Нужно постоянно сверяться со справочником, чтобы правильно выписать все цифры.

Такая запись

```
int i = 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

не требует наличия феноменальной памяти.

Но в любом случае было бы проще, лучше и яснее записать

```
int i = int.MaxValue;
```

так как такая запись самодокументируемая.

Запись

```
int i = 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

предпочтительнее предыдущей записи лишь в одном случае: когда переменная `i` используется как некоторая маска для битовых операций.

Comment: Можно ещё добавить, что при первом варианте записи можно ошибиться в одной цифре в середине, и этого никто не заметит. Во втором варианте достаточно проверить количество F после семерки)

Comment: @insolor  В принципе у меня об этом говорится.

Answer (score 2):

Часто необходимо записать двоичное беззнаковое целое. Каждая шестнадцатиричная цифра может заменить собой 4 бита в бинарном представлении, т.е. байт - две "сконкатенированных" шеснадцатиричных цифры. Это удобнее читать и записывать, чем ряды двоичных разрядов.